# Check box triggering remote link

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am in the process of converting an link into a check box.

I would like to take this

```
<%= link_to (image_tag "table.png", :alt => "Show Area(s) Table", :style => "padding-left:15px;", :id => "updateAreaTableIconId"), refresh_area_table_path({:field_id => "#{@field.id}"}), :remote => true %>
```

and create something like this

```
<input type='checkbox' id='showAreaBox' onclick='showArea(); <%= redirect_to refresh_area_table_path({:field_id => "#{@field.id}"}), :remote => true %>;'></input>
```

So in other words I want to get rid of the link and add the redirect to the onclick of the checkbox

if there is a way to trigger a remote redirect in jquery I could add it to the showArea(); method as well.

Thanks!

Comment: A "remote" link ? What do you mean ? Another link on the page ? If yes select it with jQuery and call .click like $('#mylink').click(); Or if you don't have a link, use window.open(yourUrl, '_self');

Comment: The window.open would work as long as there was a way to set remote to true.  That way it would not try to render the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to web development and I now realize that I wasn't asking the right question.
I ended up using this

```
$.post('myLink')
```

And that did what :remote => true does on link_to.
I found the answer on 2. of this article 
http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to programmatically click an anchor whenever a checkbox is checked?

Here's one way to do it:

```
var myLink = $('#myLinkId'); // assumes you have a reference to your <a/> element

$('#showAreaBox').change(function() {

    // if the checkbox is checked, invoke the link
    if( this.checked ) {
        myLink.trigger('click');
    }

    // checkbox is unchecked
    // else {}
});
```

Comment: Actually, I would like to get rid of the link and have the redirect processed when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: So instead of `myLink.trigger('click');` you want `window.location.href = myLink.attr('href');`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JS

```
$('#showAreaBox').change(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.prop('checked')) {
        if (el.data('target') == '_blank') {
            window.open(el.data('link'));
        }
        else {
            location = el.data('link');
        }
    }
});
```

HTML for Open in same window

```
<input type="checkbox" id="showAreaBox" data-link="http://www.example.com">
```

HTML for Open in new window

```
<input type="checkbox" id="showAreaBox" data-target="_blank" data-link="http://www.example.com">
```